# What is meant by something "transforming like a specific irreducible representation"? Or "transforms like the regular representation"

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

So I am trying to learn more about the representation theory of finite groups. Throughout my reading, I have consistently found the phrase "transforms like" _______ representation (fill in the blank). When reading this, I originally didn't think too much about it because I thought it was just a wierd way to describe the way you can decompose any representation of a finite group into the direct sum of irreps. But as I kept reading, I realized I don't fully understand what is meant by this phrase.

In my head, this is what I take the phrase to mean:
(also bear with me, I do not come from mathematics background so I am not too good at putting concepts into a formal language)

Given a representation $(\pi_1 , V)$ of a finite group $G$, we can decompose $V$ into $\bigoplus_{i}{n_i V_i}$, a direct sum of irreducible representations. In my head, since each of the $V_i$'s are vector subspaces of $V$, I immediately think about a general transformation on $V$ being "broken up" into transformations of each of these subspaces. If I take these transformations to be matrices, it would be like a big matrix transformation, $T$, on $V$ can be block diagonalized, where each of the individual block matrices, $T_i$, are their own linear transformations on the vector subspaces, $V_i$. Then I interpret "transforms like" to mean that if you have a transformation on $V$ like $T\vec{v}$, then you can say that certain components of $\vec{v}$ transform via matrix $T_i$ and other components may transform via matrix $T_j$, but altogether the whole vector $\vec{v}$ transforms via the whole matrix transformation $T$.

Is this an accurate interpretation? Really, I am wondering more about which *things* are supposed to transform like an irrep for example. Is it the components of some vector in the representation space that are supposed to transform this way, like only those components in that specific irrep subspace?

Comment: I believe if $V$ is a $G$-rep, we say $v\in V$ "transforms like" (or "as") the irrep $U$ if the subrep of $V$ generated by $v$ (i.e. the span of its $G$-orbit) is an isomorphic copy of $U$. I don't think I've encountered a physics or chemistry source actually say it like this, unfortunately.

Comment: @arctictern Just to clarify, the subrep of $V$ generated by $v$ is constructed by taking span$(\pi(g) v ) \quad \forall g \in G$?

Comment: Yes, it is the span of $\{\pi(g)v\mid g\in G\}$. It may also be characterized as the smallest subrep containing $v$.

Comment: So in my question I mentioned that I think about a transformation matrix $T$ on $V = \bigoplus_{i}{n_i V_i}$ as a block diagonal matrix, but would it be more accurate to say this $T$ is in general not diagonal, but that it can be block diagonalized? @arctictern

Comment: Any *equivariant* aka *intertwining* operator on $V$ can be block-diagonalized with respect to the isotypic components $n_iV_i$ of $V$ (and indeed each such block acts as an $n_i\times n_i$ matrix with scalar multiplication on the chosen copies of $V_i$). This follows from Schur's lemma and hom-distributivity.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your comments! @arctictern